# IONIC Framework - template is getting reloaded 10-12 times & so the controller functions

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have verified, controller is getting loaded only once not multiple times. Also, If I add more routes in app.js the number of print keeps increasing as well.

Issue demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXxxpM (check console in browser)

```
.controller('AuthSignUpCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
   var i=01;
   $scope.test = function() {
      console.log(i++);
   };
});


$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login1',
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'AuthSignUpCtrl'
    });
```

Comment: Made another state, didn't print more [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZgMzP?editors=1111)

Comment: Ok, but hope u were able to see the original problem .

Comment: Can i know Ionic version? Because in one of the version they have issue of multiple time calling controller (Ionic 1.2.0#alpha) Might be the one

Comment: Yes, the version is v1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your template is being reloaded.
I think its because you bound your function to an expression. 
Try typing into the text box, this will cause the digest loop to cycle and will fire your function, resulting in more output in the console.